# Can i draw precise sphere in perspective using illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I really need to draw ellipses and spheres in perspective so I wonder if Illustrator is set to do this kind of tasks, I tried and came up with this result: 
[image: Sphere In perspective]

But as you can see It's not precise and it takes a lot of time to draw ellipses in perspective, So I wonder if anyone came across a better way or maybe a better appllication for perspectiv drawing??

Comment: That image does not look like its in perspective the edges are parallel, its some sort of a parallel projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Illustrator's **3D Rotate** feature.

1. Draw your ellipse
2. Select your ellipse
3. Click `Effect > 3D > Rotate`
4. Adjust the various axis and click `OK`

The result will be your original shape with the live effect applied to it, which you can go back into and adjust. When you're happy, click `Object > Expand Appearance` to convert your 3D shape to a path.

Comment: That's cool, and I really can draw a sphere with that, but what if I want to fit an ellipse inside an already existing rectangle in perspective??  I guess I can't use rotation to do that, so do you have any other workaround? and thanks for your help

Comment: Try drawing a circle and a matching square, grouping them, and then using 3D Rotate (with 'Preview' ticked) to match the perspective of your rectangle.

Comment: doesn't that demand that I know the size of the square in perspective?? or do you mean I try different sizes till I match it?? trial and error??

Comment: A bit of trial and error, unfortunately! But using 3D Rotate means that you can adjust the size of the square and the angle of your rotation until you get it perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible. But remember that the perspective projection of a sphere is actually an ellipse ([see this explanation](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/does-a-sphere-projected-into-2d-space-always-result-in-an-ellipse/1500#1500).

[image]

**Image 1**: A isometric spheres (left) projection is a circle. In a perspective that projection is actually an ellipsoid.

First find the approximate center draw a approximate sphere (tip holding space lets you move center) then rotate the sphere to cardinal direction and scale it up a bit. Takes about 2 minutes to be almost accurate once you've practiced. This is by far more accurate than trying to eyeball the settings for 3D Rotate or 3D revolve.

#### Finding the projected ellipses major axis

The major axis of the ellipse is oriented towards the center of your perspective or simply the one point perspective vanishing point.

[image]

**Image 2**: The major axis of the projected ellipse

... How do i draw this? ... sorry must go again

Comment: I understand the projection, But i don't understand how did you do it?? in my first picture i draw rectangle for every ellipse and used pen tool.. but i don't understand how you did it?

Comment: @Corabict yes i got interrupted

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but my problem isn't in the perspective construction but how to implement it precisely Inside illustrator, So I'm waiting for you

Comment: Yeah, until @joojaa actually answers the OP's question, gonna have to downvote this one...